# Does $A\times A\cong B\times B$ imply $A\cong B$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, type-theory, constructive-mathematics

This is similar to [What does it take to divide by $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024397/what-does-it-take-to-divide-by-2) about $(A\sqcup A\cong B\sqcup B)\Rightarrow A\cong B$ which is valid in $\textsf{ZFC}$ by using cardinalities and also in $\textsf{ZF}$ by some combinatorial argument, but where it remained unclear whether constructive arguments suffice.

This questions concerns products instead of disjoint union, so:

> *Question:* Does $\textsf{ZF}$ prove the implication $(A\times A\cong B\times B)\Rightarrow A\cong B$?

If yes: is anything known in case of *intuitionistic* set/type theories?

Comment: @bof Thank you! I'm aware of the result about the 'injectivity' of $n\times -$, but where can I find the result about $(-)^2$ (or even $(-)^n$)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I seem to be befuddled. Never mind!

Comment: @bof: No worries, and thanks for carefully looking up the references! Would you mind copying your answer to the question about divisibility by $2$? Even though it wasn't about intuitionistic reasoning, I think it is valuable for anyone generally interested in the topic.

Comment: Why isnt' it enough to project onto the first component to get $A\cong B$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a generalization of tetori's nice answer, which in fact shows that this assumption implies the axiom of choice.

> **Lemma I.** If $a$ and $b$ are infinite cardinals equipollent with their own squares, then $(a+b)^2=a\cdot b$.

*Proof.* We calculate:
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2\cdot a\cdot b=a^2+b^2+a\cdot b=a+b+a\cdot b=a\cdot b$$
The second equality comes from the fact that $a\leq a+a=2\cdot a\leq a^2=a$, the last one follows from the same reasoning. $\qquad\square$

> **Lemma II.** If $a+a=a$ then $2^a$ equals to its own square.

*Proof.* $(2^a)^2=2^{a+a}=2^a.\qquad\square$

> **Tarski's Lemma.** If $a$ is a cardinal, $\lambda$ is an aleph, and $a+\lambda=a\cdot\lambda$, then the two are comparable.

(The proof appears in Jech, The Axiom of Choice, Lemma 11.6; and there are generalizations of this lemma out there.)

> **Theorem. ($\sf ZF$)** If $a^2=b^2\implies a=b$ for infinite cardinals, then the axiom of choice holds.

*Proof.* We will show that if $\kappa$ is an aleph number, then $2^\kappa$ is an aleph number. This implies the axiom of choice, by a theorem of Rubin and Rubin from 1963.

Let $\lambda=\aleph(2^\kappa)$, the least aleph cardinal such that $\lambda\nleq 2^\kappa$. Then $2^\kappa$ and $\lambda$ satisfy the hypothesis of Lemma I, and therefore $(2^\kappa+\lambda)^2=2^\kappa\cdot\lambda=(2^\kappa)^2\cdot\lambda^2=(2^\kappa\cdot\lambda)^2$. By the uniqueness of the square root, $2^\kappa+\lambda=2^\kappa\cdot\lambda$, and by Tarski's lemma $2^\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are comparable.

Finally $\lambda\nleq2^\kappa$, therefore $2^\kappa<\lambda$, so $2^\kappa$ is an aleph number. $\qquad\square$

(I will remark here that the final proof uses $\sf ZF$ in a substantial way. In $\sf ZFA$, where atoms are allowed, having $2^\kappa$ as an aleph does not imply the axiom of choice.)

Comment: Dear Asaf, thanks alot! Just to make sure I get it: how do we know that $2^{\kappa}$ and $\aleph(2^\kappa)$ are equal to their own squares? For $2^{\kappa}$, Lemma II tells that it is sufficient to have $\kappa+\kappa = \kappa$, which holds since $2\cdot\lambda$ (ordinal multiplication) has order type $\lambda$ for every limit ordinal $\lambda$, and for $\aleph(2^\kappa)^2=\aleph(2^\kappa)$ we may use $\alpha\beta=\text{max}\{\alpha,\beta\}$ for $\aleph$-cardinals $\alpha,\beta$?

Comment: Anyway, +1 of course for this very helpful answer.

Comment: The usual cardinal arithmetic is provable for aleph numbers without choice, choice is needed to show every cardinal is an aleph.

Comment: Aha, ok, then everything's clear.

Comment: It would be interesting to know if the theorem even holds in any elementary topos, i.e. if $X^2\cong Y^2\Rightarrow X\cong Y$ implies that the topos satisfies AC.

Comment: Well, I'm definitely the wrong man for *that* question. I think a good start would be to see if it holds in $\sf ZFA$.

Comment: I just saw in Halbeisen's book the unsurprising fact that this equivalence to AC is due to Tarski. I'm guessing that the proof is probably along the line I present here.

Comment: @Asaf regarding Hanno's question, a start would be to see if the above holds in BZ

Comment: @David: Isn't that KP+Power set?

Comment: @Asaf Bounded Zermelo. I.e. no replacement, and with bounded separation, IIRC

Comment: @David: Yes, I understood that. I was being a smartypants since it's 3AM. :-)

Comment: @Asaf well, it's really the theory of a well-pointed topos with natural number object, but since it's 3am, I didn't want to tax you... ;-)

Comment: @David: Taxes like that causes George Bush Sr. not to get re-elected! :-P

Comment: But seriously, can the above be done in BZ? Maybe sleep on it...

Answer (score 10):

The answer is no. It is known that ZF+'$\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ are incomparable' is consistent if ZF does. Assume that $\aleph_1$ and $2^{\aleph_0}$ are incomparable (over ZF),then

1. $\aleph_1$, $2^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0}$ and
2. $\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0}\neq\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$.

1 is trivial. To prove 2, we can use following theorem:

> **Theorem** (ZF) If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a (possibly non-well-orderable) cardinal and $\alpha$ is an aleph and they satisfy $\mathfrak{p}+\alpha=\mathfrak{p}\cdot\alpha$, then they are comparable.

You can find this theorem and its proof in Jech's 'Axiom of choice', Lemma 11.16.

We will check that $(\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0})^2=(\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0})^2=\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$. It is just a calculation:
$$
\begin{align}(\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0})^2
&=\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0}+2\cdot \aleph_1\cdot2^{\aleph_0}\\
&=\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0}+\aleph_1\cdot2^{\aleph_0}\\
&=\aleph_1+(\aleph_1+1)\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}\\
&=\aleph_1+\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}\\
&=\aleph_1\cdot(1+2^{\aleph_0})\\
&=\aleph_1\cdot2^{\aleph_0}.\\
\end{align}$$
Also, the square of $\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$ is $\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$ itself so $(\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0})^2=(\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0})^2$. However, we already know that $\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\aleph_1\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}$ are not equal.

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}<\aleph_1+2^{\aleph_0}$: This is false, isn't it?

Comment: @Tony: No, it's not false. It is consistent that $\aleph_1$ is incomparable with $2^{\aleph_0}$, in which case the strict inequality is true.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Ah, OK: in a model containing incomparable cardinals, it can't be true that $\kappa+\mu=\max(\kappa,\mu)$ for infinite cardinals $\kappa,\mu$, because $\max(\kappa,\mu)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: @Tony: Yes, and every model of $\lnot\sf AC$ contains incomparable cardinals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Therefore, "All cardinals are comparable" implies AC? If so, that's a surprise to me.

Comment: @TonyK Yes. If every cardinals are comparable, then every set can embed into some ordinal. To be more exact, Hartogs number of the set has larger cardinality than the set.

Comment: @AsafKaragila and tetori: Thank you both for an enlightening session!

Comment: Dear tetori, thank you very much!

Answer (score 8):

**This does not answer the question (which I misread, being in a mental fog), but I am undeleting it at the OP's request.**

The following summary is copied from p. 174 of Wacław Sierpiński, *Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers*, second edition revised, Warszawa, 1965:

> *If, for a natural number $k$ and cardinal numbers $m$ and $n$, we have $km=kn$, then $m=n$.*

This theorem was proved without the aid of the axiom of choice for $k=2$ in 1905 by F. Bernstein, who also outlined a proof for natural $k$ (Bernstein [1], p. 122; also Sierpiński [8], p. 1). A detailed proof for natural $k$ (without the aid of the axiom of choice) was published by A. Tarski [12] (p. 77). who proved also (without the aid of the axiom of choice) that if for a natural number $k$ and cardinal numbers $m$ and $n$ we have $km\le kn$, then $m\le n$ (for $k=2$ see also Sierpiński [31], p. 148).

F. Bernstein, *Untersuchungen aus der Mengenlehre*, Math. Annalen 61 (1905), p. 117-155.

W. Sierpiński, *Sur l'égalité $2m=2n$ pour les nombres cardinaux*, Fund. Math. 3 (1922), p. 1-16.

W. Sierpiński, *Sur l'implication $(2m\le2n)\rightarrow(m\le n)$ pour les nombres cardinaux*, Fund. Math. 34 (1947), p. 148-154.

A. Tarski, *Cancellation laws in the arithmetic of cardinals*, Fund. Math. 36 (1949), p. 77-92.

Comment: Thank you for collecting the references!